# <Article> va dentro de <section> o al reves?

Tags: html, css

Estoy viendo que mucha gente pone el section dentro del article o al reves y a veces ponen el section y el article no, A que se debe. Pd: Soy nuevo.

```html
 <article>
    <section>
       lfsdjkfjkjdf
       sdfisdfjlsdf
       
    
    </section
 </article>
```

Comment: Pueden ir en ambos sentidos, dependiendo de los usos semánticos que tenga la estructura del sitio y no afecta en nada

Answer (score 1):

Se puede de las dos maneras, esto dependiendo de la estructura de la web.

Pueden ir juntos, uno dentro de otro y viceversa e incluso por separado.

El section nada más define una sección del documento.

El articulo, especifica un contenido independiente o autónomo.

Answer (score 0):

De forma primaria partimos que ambas son [elementos de bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) por lo cual la una puede contener a la otra....

**Sin embargo**

El sentido semántico es el que debe tener mayor relevancia a la hora de identificar si se puede o no, dicho lo anterior revisemos.

De acuerdo con la [especificación de dichas etiquetas](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#sectioning-content) ambas son:

- Etiquetas de seccionadoras

**Una etiqueta [`section`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)**

Por si misma representa dentro de un sitio web elementos tales como:

- Información de contacto
- Elementos noticias
- Introducción

Mientras que **una etiqueta [`article`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element)** sirve para identificar dentro de un sitio web:

- Aquel contenido que pueda ser [sindicado](https://dle.rae.es/sindicar) y que dicho eso sirve indexar para hacerlo accesible  e identificable al usuario
- Contenido que es reusable
- Contenido de una naturaleza independiente, tales como:

  - Entradas de blog
  - Un artículo de una revista
  - etc.

> Ahora por ejemplo aunque un `section` pueda tener incluidos dentro múltiples `articles` con contenido de naturaleza independiente como los anteriormente listados incluso estos a su vez pueden tener mas etiquetas `article` anidadas dentro de ellas; es decir un `article` con `articles` internos anidados.

Entonces...

Aunque el navegador de forma explícita no te va a mostrar un error si haces el acomodo que tu decidas, dada la naturaleza de uso de cada una entonces hace mas sentido:

**Edito pues me equivoqué en la idea expuesta**

Que un article contenga elementos section dentro de si tantos como la estructura ocupe y sean necesarios ya que el del contenido que será indexado es el primero mencionado